# Failed to Register Service Worker - An SSL certificate error occurred when fetching the script

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, spfx, ssl, pwa

I have created an application with self signed certificate in my test server. My service worker is not getting registered and throwing the following error in console -

Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://demo:15250/sites/SharePointPOC/Style%20Library/') with script ('https://demo:15250/sites/SharePointPOC/Style%20Library/sw.js'): An SSL certificate error occurred when fetching the script.

Can we use a service worker with a self-signed certificate in a live server?